# Is there a benefit to using Hurt Points other than making it difficult for other characters?

Tags: city-of-mist

I was looking over the Help and Hurt points of the Juice section. It makes sense why Help points are useful, but my first impression was that Hurt Points are solely used to complicate things for other characters.

Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

## You say "complicated" like it's a bad thing.

There is, of course, the simpler case, where diplomacy has failed and you've all come to blows, and even if what you're about to do isn't going to rack status on a fellow player, it'll still make their lives terrible for your benefit and that's a choice you have to make, so you spend the Hurt to take firm control of the consequences of your betrayal.

But Hurt can be a little more involved than that, too.

> Hurt points represent your desire and ability to hurt your crewmate, whether by taking actions to hurt her or by interfering with the actions she takes. They can only be used to create effects that enhance actions you take to hurt your crewmate or interfere with actions your crewmate takes. **In rare cases, when you believe supporting your crewmate's action would hurt her, you may use a Hurt point to create effects that enhance her action.**
>
> -- *City of Mist Player's Guide*, p.236 (added emphasis mine)

Getting the courage to make a play for Bloodstone Jimmy's capo chair? Stealing the last key component to a crucial and risky ritual? Breaking out of Penners Island lockup? How are any of those possibly going to end well for you?

But darned if you haven't seen all of them happen and everything get worse as Act 2 in a three-act structure thundered on.

Now, everybody sitting down at the table knows what you're bad at. They know what your story can't handle. They know how your connections to the real world are fraying. And Heaven knows the MC is going to look at all those points of weakness and say, sure, you can totally get that thing you gotta have right now! You want to call off the hit, you want to tell Pan Hermes to his face that his walls can go screw, you want your freedom on this night of all critical stellar conjunction nights? Here's your shiny golden wire of hope! *But it'll cost ya*...

I mean, maybe you don't run like that, maybe you're not in a group of players who like to dance on the edge and don't care if they fall in. It's not an easy life! But you've all had the chance to sit down and talk with each other about what your Crew is and how they got together, and how you treat each other. That was *A Day in the Life*, right? You know if you're sitting down with a bunch of folks who like to play Happy Families, absent the MC getting cruel again and turning you, one on another. So maybe you don't play for Hurt. It's pretty much always your choice to take it.

That Hurt point still means something if it's never used, after all. At creation, it means there's something in your mythologos that lets you mistrust someone, and that "something" is true. When you're going over the credits, it means that someone else did something that's making you mistrust them, and that "something" is also true. It can still drive the story, even if it never comes out and plays dice with the rest.

But if you do run with a bunch of daredevils and enthusiastically speed each other into danger? Hurt can be a very interesting engine to get yourself wonderfully imperiled.

> "I can see we're going to get along like a house on fire," said Miss Tick. "There may be no survivors."
>
> -- Terry Pratchett, *The Wee Free Men*